# Not able to convert and access Tuples of bytes array and convert to string in Java using web3j

Tags: contract-development, web3j, java

I am new to the development of smart contract using web3j. I am facing issue, while converting Bytes32[] returned from wrapper of contract(.sol) method to array.

I have contract as:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract Person
{
    Person[] public people;

    struct Person
    {
        bytes32 firstName;
        bytes32 lastName;

    }

    function addPerson(bytes32 _firstName, bytes32 _lastname) returns (bool success)
    {
        Person memory newPerson;

        newPerson.firstName = _firstName;
        newPerson.lastName = _lastname;


        people.push(newPerson);
        return true;
    }

    function getPeople() constant returns (bytes32[], bytes32[])
    {
        uint leng = people.length;

        bytes32[] memory first_names = new bytes32[](leng);
        bytes32[] memory last_names = new bytes32[](leng);


        for (uint i = 0; i < people.length; i++ )
        {
            Person memory currentPerson;
            currentPerson = people[i];
            first_names[i] = (currentPerson.firstName);
            last_names[i] = (currentPerson.lastName);


        }
        return (first_names,last_names);
    }
}


Function from generated java wrapper as:




    public RemoteCall<Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>>> getPeople() {
        final Function function = new Function("getPeople", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Bytes32>>() {}, new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Bytes32>>() {}));
        return new RemoteCall<Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>>>(
                new Callable<Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>> call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> results = executeCallMultipleValueReturn(function);;
                        return new Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>>(
                                (List<byte[]>) results.get(0).getValue(), 
                                (List<byte[]>) results.get(1).getValue());
                    }
                });
    }
```

In my main function, I am trying access Bytes of Array returned from getPeople method. But I am not note able to converted Bytes of array to string.
I am storing tuples values in main method as:

```
Tuple2<List<byte[]>, List<byte[]>> x = contract.getPeople().send();
```

I want to convert value, `x.getValue1()` to string. Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your hex or byte in this method will return you the string..

var hexToUtf8 = function(hex) {
    if (!isHexStrict(hex))
        throw new Error('The parameter "'+ hex +'" must be a valid HEX string.');

```
var str = "";
var code = 0;
hex = hex.replace(/^0x/i,'');

// remove 00 padding from either side
hex = hex.replace(/^(?:00)*/,'');
hex = hex.split("").reverse().join("");
hex = hex.replace(/^(?:00)*/,'');
hex = hex.split("").reverse().join("");

var l = hex.length;

for (var i=0; i < l; i+=2) {
    code = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
    // if (code !== 0) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(code);
    // }
}

return utf8.decode(str);
```

};